# Material multipliers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying, without success so far, to figure out an Excel formula to average material multipliers with multiple criteria. A material multiplier is a number less than 1.0000. The criteria are as follows:

1. If only one number is less than 1.0000, that should be the average.
2. If multiple numbers are less than 1.0000, the average should be
   calculated with only those numbers less than 1.0000.
3. If all numbers are 1.0000, then the average should be 1.0000 (there is no
   multiplier)

Comment: Welcome to SU.  Could you please provide a small sample of your data to help highlight what you're trying to accomplish.  This looks like it should be able to be completed with simple IF formula (or something similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where `A1:A8` is the range of material multipliers, you can use the following:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(A1:A8,"<1"),1)
```

This will average only the entries less than 1. If no such entries exist (i.e., all values are equal to 1.00), the formula will return `1`.

Comment: This worked exactly as needed, thanks for your help!